# Android Studio error involving Markdown editor

Tags: android-studio

I just installed a support package for Android Studio. Now it won't sync an Android project because of an error involving a Markdown package:

```
2016-11-15 06:24:07,147 [   2770]  ERROR -    #com.intellij.lang.Language - Language with ID 'Markdown' is already registered: class com.vladsch.idea.multimarkdown.MarkdownLanguage
```

Is there any way to uninstall this package or tell Android Studio to ignore it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems this is caused by Markdown Plugin ([website](https://github.com/vsch/idea-multimarkdown/)), **maybe** by [this issue](https://github.com/vsch/idea-multimarkdown/issues/295), so you can either check if there's no newer version available or simply [uninstall it](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/installing-updating-and-uninstalling-repository-plugins.html#uninstall) unless the issue is fixed. If the issue above is not really the same, fill new bug report there's so author can take a look.